# Why i'm not getting my custom post type name with get_post_type()

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

Little bit help need with my this code. I'm facing this issue for around 2 days but unable to figure it out.

> I want to get my custom post type name which i registered.

```
 $type = get_post_type();
        echo "<h1>Post type is $type</h1>";
        if(get_query_var( 'post_type' ) !== 'jobs'){

            return $original_template;

        }
```

> How i registered my custom post type is below:

```
function dwwp_register_post_type() {

    $singular = __( 'Job' );
    $plural = __( 'Jobs' );
        //Used for the rewrite slug below.
        $plural_slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', $plural );

        //Setup all the labels to accurately reflect this post type.
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => $plural,
        'singular_name'         => $singular,
        'add_new'               => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'edit'                  => 'Edit',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'new_item'              => 'New ' . $singular,
        'view'                  => 'View ' . $singular,
        'view_item'             => 'View ' . $singular,
        'search_term'           => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'parent'                => 'Parent ' . $singular,
        'not_found'             => 'No ' . $plural .' found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No ' . $plural .' in Trash'
    );

        //Define all the arguments for this post type.
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-site',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        // 'capabilities' => array(),
        'rewrite'             => array( 
            'slug' => 'jobs',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title'
        )
    );

        //Create the post type using the above two varaiables.
    register_post_type( 'jobs', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_cpt_args = array(
'public'   => true,
'_builtin' => false
);

$post_types = get_post_types( $get_cpt_args, 'object' );
if(($post_types ) !== 'jobs') {

  echo "Post type is not a jobs";
} else {

  echo "Post type is jobs";
}
```

try this with your custom post type. this might help you.